# In graph theory, what is linked list?

Tags: graph-theory

In graph theory, does linked list mean adjacency list or something different ? If it is different, can you explain ?

Comment: Can you provide more context for this term?

Comment: As far as I can tell, "linked list" is not a term from graph theory, but rather from informatics. A linked list is a collection of objects where each object (except a "last" one) has a pointer to a "next" object. The resulting graph(!) is a directed line graph.

Answer (score 3):

A linked list is a data structure, built up from a node, the data in that node, a pointer to the next node, and sometimes a pointer to the previous node. You could put an adjacency list into a linked list if you wanted, but you could also load it into an array or other structure.

Answer (score 1):

*Adjacency list* and *linked list* are concepts at different levels:

- One representations for a graph is by a list of vertices with an adjacency list for each vertex.
- One implementation for an adjacency list is with a linked list.

In both cases, there are other possibilities.

The abstract concept is that of a *list*. A linked list is one implementation for abstract lists. An adjacency list is just a list with the semantics for representing graphs.